# Stored Procedure error - incorrect syntax near else

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on my first stored procedure, and it's showing an error at the else (where I have a comment at the else below). If anyone knows how I can fix the error, I'd appreciate it. I've tried looking online, and I think it may have to do with my begin/end and if/else positioning.  I'm having trouble finding a similar example though.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE procedure [dbo].[SPName]
    @userid NVARCHAR(51)
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @return_status  INT

    IF @userid IS NULL OR @userid = 0
    BEGIN
        --fail
        SET @return_status = 1
    END

    IF  @return_status <> 1
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT login
                   FROM dbo.user_table
                   WHERE (@userid = login))
        --continue because its a good user
        ELSE  
            -- this is where it doesn't like the else
            SET @return_status = 1
    END

    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.U_MEMBER
        SET dbo.U_MEMBER.inac = 1,
            dbo.U_MEMBER.reg = @userid
        FROM dbo.U_MEMBER
        WHERE U_MEMBER.VF = 'REV'
    END

    RETURN 0
```

Comment: On line 27 (of that specific set of batches) you start an `IF`, but you don't have a *something* to do if it's true. You go straight to an `ELSE`. An `IF` need something to do when the `IF` evaluates to true.

Comment: On a different note, 3 part naming for columns is to be deprecated/removed from SQL Server. Ideally stick to 2 part naming and aliasing when referencing columns; then you won't be caught out when it happens.

Comment: Also, is the intention of `SET @return_status=1` to fail the SP, because it doesn't. In fact, the second time is it set achieves nothing, as it's never referenced against afterwards. Seems like you might be better off with `THROW` for the first `IF` and a custom error message.

Comment: A foreign key between U_MEMBER and user_table would negate the need for an existence check. There is a lot to be improved in this schema and code. Some investigation into best practices is advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IF` statement has nothing to do if it equates to true:

```
IF  @return_status <> 1
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(select login from dbo.user_table where  (@userid=login))
        --continue because its a good user
    ELSE  --this is where it doesn't like the else
        set @return_status = 1
    END
...
```

This is syntactically incorrect.  TSQL is expecting a statement to be executed if the `IF` returns true, and in this case a comment is not sufficient.

If you don't need to do anything if the statement is true, just switch to `IF NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
IF  @return_status <> 1
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(select login from dbo.user_table where  (@userid=login))
    BEGIN
        set @return_status = 1
    END
...
```

Otherwise if you want to use both the true and false outcomes of the `IF` statement:

```
IF  @return_status <> 1
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(select login from dbo.user_table where  (@userid=login))
    BEGIN
        -- Do something with the true outcome
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        set @return_status = 1
    END
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize @return_status variable, for example:

```
DECLARE @return_status  INT

--Initialize the variable with the expected value
SET @return_status = 0

IF @userid IS NULL OR @userid = 0
BEGIN
--fail
    SET @return_status=1
END
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks.  It's not the reason why I have the error.  I'm going to accept the other answer and up-vote your answer as being helpful.